# How to calculate the total time user watched a video

Tags: video, html5-video, media-player

I have a list of videos played using html5 video player.
Here I need to calculate the total time the user watched a video.
I tried the same using listners but that was not accurate.
The video duration has to be calculated in seconds.

```
totalPlaytime = 0;

video.addEventListener("play", (event) => {
    
    start = performance.now();

});

video.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", (event) => {

    if (!document.fullscreenElement) {
        end = performance.now();
        totalPlaytime += end - start;
        let end_date_time = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD H:mm:ss");
        let duration = totalPlaytime/1000;
        saveMediaLog(start_date_time, end_date_time, duration);//Ajax call to save 
    }

});
```

Comment: Most likely you need a **Timer** to check every second (every 1000ms), the `currentTime` to see if it has increased (means user is going forward in time), you also need to keep a `furthest_time_reached` variable updated if the time goes forward (so if user rewinds then the new `currentTime` is smaller than the `furthest_time_reached` variable and you can ignore such times without adding them to your `totalPlaytime` variable. That's the simplest without creating a more complicated (better) system.